# Autodesk Token Flex API - GET contract empty body response

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to get our contract number using the Token Flex API. The GET contract endpoint returns 200 OK but the response body is empty. Shouldn't it always return something if the request succeeded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token Flex API only work for Entreprise Account (EBA) with a TokenFlex server. In order to use that API, you need your Forge account and client ID associated with your EBA account. For doing this, please liaise with your CSM to get it registered on the system. If you still see an issue, please contact us at forge.help email address (@autodesk.com) with an example of the query where you have a problem and share the client ID you are using.